# How can I disable Tablet Mode programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have a Surface Pro that I use for sketching with my stylus. I want to be able to quickly enable/disable tablet mode without going into Device Manager.

I've been searching for ways to do this: by disabling drivers, disabling by HID but everything I've found seems overly complicated for what I need. I'm creating just a form with a CheckBox. What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Tablet mode isn't controlled by the device manager, it's a feature of the operating system. You should be looking at the SDK of the OS you are interested in (although I suspect it's at least Windows 8). The question is more likely to get an answer if it's tagged with the appropriate OS tag too. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I've retagged it. I'm working in Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like setting the Registry Key to 0

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell]
"TabletMode"=dword:00000000
```

If TabletMode = 1 then it'll be enabled.

```
    RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell", true);
   if(myKey != null)
   {
   myKey.SetValue("TabletMode", "0", RegistryValueKind.dWord);
   myKey.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Sean: myKey is returning Null.

Comment: Changed it to Registry.CurrentUser... and got rid of "HKEY..."

Comment: I missed that one on the first time through, my apologies. I haven't touched Registry Keys for about 3 years now; this was just from memory.

Comment: I set the TabletMode to 1 but Tablet Mode didn't turn on. The registry value did change however.

Comment: I did the same thing. It didn't change to tablet mode.