# Why isn't Windows 10 exiting Tablet mode when I programatically change the TabletMode registry key value from my C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, tablet

I have a WPF application that runs on a mix of Windows 10 desktops and tablets. I want to programmatically switch out of Windows 10 tablet mode when the application starts.

I found this link ([How can I disable Tablet Mode programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481916/how-can-i-disable-tablet-mode-programmatically)) to show how to make the required registry changes. When I execute my application, I can verify that the registry setting is changed (I use REGEDIT, locate the appropriate key, verify that TabletMode is DWORD 0. But the tablet is still in tablet mode.)

I found another link ([Windows 10 tablet mode Registry setting: 'When this device automatically switches tablet mode on or off'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187260/windows-10-tablet-mode-registry-setting-when-this-device-automatically-switche)) that indicates that another registry value is needed to indicate to Windows when to change tablet mode. This does not appear to work either.

Is there another registry setting and/or API call that I need to make to cause Windows to exit tablet mode?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498124/7252182)?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply... Yes, I did see it, but there's lots of intricate code in that repository, and I was hoping that someone might have come across this same problem and could offer some specific guidance.